# Node.js and Express - different result Windows 7 vs Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: node.js, express, powershell-2.0

This code in app.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    port    = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(app.router);
 });

app.listen(port);

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log("Body: " + req.body);
    res.send({ status: 'SUCCESS' });
});
```

Running

```
 PS C:\> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"type":"server","name":"SERVER1"}' http://localhost:3000/
```

results in:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token t
at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous (C:\temp\neo4jstest2\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\json.js
:76:27)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at _stream_readable.js:910:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I have tested the same code on Ubuntu 13.04 and it works fine.

Is there any difference or tweaks to make on Windows to make it work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows command line  doesn't like the use of single quotes.  I haven't tried this, but I believe this will work:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"type\":\"server\",\"name\":\"SERVER1\"}"
```

The single quotes have been replaced with double quotes and the internal double quotes have been escaped.

**Update**

I was able to get this working on my local windows 7 (64bit) machine:

```
C:\>f:\util\curl.exe -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"type\":\"server\",\"name\":\"SERVER1\"}" http://localhost:3000/
{
  "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

curl version (just downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/)

```
C:\>f:\util\curl.exe --version
curl 7.31.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.31.0
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap ldap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate Largefile NTLM SSPI
```

Node Version:

```
C:\>node --version
v0.8.18
```

Running with single quotes (with both escaped double quotes and unescaped double quotes) resulted in this error:

```
Error: invalid json
    at Object.exports.error (F:\tmp\stackoverflow\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\utils.js:62:13)
    at IncomingMessage.module.exports (F:\tmp\stackoverflow\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\json.js:74:71)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at IncomingMessage._emitEnd (http.js:366:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:149:23)
    at Socket.socket.ondata (http.js:1786:22)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:404:27)
```

Comment: No didn't work tried several combinations of escaping: SyntaxError: Unexpected token \

Comment: Just tried this on win7 and it worked for me - will update answer with details.

Comment: Thanks you put me on the right track. Something fishy about quotes. Used powershell instead:

Answer (score 1):

Powershell to the rescue:

```
PS:\> $body = ConvertTo-Json @{"type" = "server"; "name" = "SERVER1"}
PS:\> Invoke-WebRequest -Body $body -Uri http://localhost:3000/ -ContentType application/json -Method POST
```

Answer (score 0):

For my Windows 64-bit machine using curl, this worked for me:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST
 -d "{\"firstName\":\"First\", \"lastName\":\"Last\", \"email\":\"user@example.c
om\", \"username\":\"username\", \"password\":\"password\"}" localhost:3000/user
s
```